# NSTask and NSPipe example to comunicate with the command line objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface, nstask

Can someone show a quick example on how to use NSTask and NSPipe in conjunction to do this:

Charlie AI - run through terminal to comunicate with the AI

I want to create a nice GUI for it using xcode and objective c. I want to have 2 NSTextFields for the charlie's response and user input. Then have a send button to send the user input to the command line, then get the charlie's response and post it in the NSTextField.

I can handle the GUI stuff (NSTextField, ect.) But I need help with the objective-c coding part.

Thanks!

Elijah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has some nice sample code that shows how to do most of that.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Moriarity/Introduction/Intro.html

`TaskWrapper.m` contains all the clever stuff, but since you want to be able to send data to the task, you'll need to extend it a little, like so:

```m
[task setStandardInput: [NSPipe pipe]];
```

To send input to the task, you can then do:

```m
[[[task standardInput] fileHandleForWriting] writeData: ...];
```

To turn the NSTextField's value into data, you can do something like this:

```m
NSData *data = [[inputTextField stringValue] 
                dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

...and to set the current working directory for your sub-task, use
[`[NSTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask/1413110-currentdirectorypath)

e.g.

```c
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath: @"/blah/blah"];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/blah/blah/server.sh"];

.... (other setup code)

[task launch];
```

Comment: 1 more thing...how would I send "cd /blah/blah" and then "./server.sh" to start charlie?

Comment: Updated my response to show how to do that... hope it helps :-)

Comment: Also, how do get the data from the terminal after I sent something? I'm confused with how moriarity does it.

Answer (score 1):

There's also AMShellWrapper sample code which improves on moriarity.

http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php