# server.sh gives me following error Exception"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, exception

i am trying to start the "Program D" from the terminal,
command in terminal "sh server.sh" gives me following error

```
Starting Alicebot Program D. Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/alicebot/server/net/AliceServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.alicebot.server.net.AliceServer     at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

My Server.sh file

```
ALICE_HOME=.SERVLET_LIB=lib/servlet.jar
ALICE_LIB=lib/aliceserver.jar
JS_LIB=lib/js.jar

# Set SQL_LIB to the location of your database driver.
SQL_LIB=lib/mysql_comp.jar

# These are for Jetty; you will want to change these if you are using a different http         server.
    HTTP_SERVER_LIBS=lib/org.mortbay.jetty.jar:lib/javax.xml.jaxp.jar:lib/org.apache.crimson.jar

PROGRAMD_CLASSPATH=$SERVLET_LIB:$ALICE_LIB:$JS_LIB:$SQL_LIB:$HTTP_SERVER_LIBS
java -classpath $PROGRAMD_CLASSPATH -Xms64m -Xmx64m org.alicebot.server.net.AliceServer $1
```

Comment: Obvious question is, are you sure `org.alicebot.server.net.AliceServer` is in one of your .jar files? Check with `jar tf`

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks org.alicebot.server.net.aliceserver its not there as a jar file, it is a java class file rooted under "programd/src/org/alicebot/server/net/aliceserver.java" would it be alright if i use aliceserver.java instead of .jar in server.sh fil?

Comment: Well, that's your problem! You don't even have a compiled copy of the class available to Java. You have to feed in compiled .class files, or .jar files containing .class files. You can put the root directory of your compiler output as a classpath element. You have many errors here; you need to go back to figure out the basics of running a Java program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be the problem?

```
ALICE_HOME=.SERVLET_LIB=lib/servlet.jar
```

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527447/how-would-i-run-an-sh-file-using-nstask-and-get-its-output) using a similar `server.sh` where this was on two lines:

```
ALICE_HOME=.
SERVLET_LIB=lib/servlet.jar
```

In your case `SERVLET_LIB` isn't getting set properly (or at all), and the embedded equal sign may be breaking `PROGRAMD_CLASSPATH` later on.