# Link against an executable in objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, hyperlink, executable, binaryfiles

Say you want to use functionality or interact with another third-party application.
Is it possible to link against an executable in an objective-c project?
Can the binary maybe be wrapped inside a framework?

Comment: You can easily run a command line tool from within an app, if that's what you want ? The tool can be anywhere, e.g. in your bundle or anywhere in the user's `PATH`.

Comment: If the third-party application is not programmed for external scripting or manipulation, then this task might not be very easy. If the third-party application is just a command-line tool then you could include the tool as a resource in your application bundle and use `NSTask` to launch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XCode copy files phase to put an additional executable in with your main one, in Your.app/Contents/MacOS, then (let's say you copied `grep`) to locate it use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"grep"]`.

I do it a little differently, for example I have a Python program one of my apps calls (getting the response in plist format which is nice) and I just have it copied into the My.app/Contents/Resources directory and use [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myScript" ofType:@"py"] to find it.

Which way you do it is, I suspect, a matter of taste. I think it makes sense to put compiled executables in with the main one, and Python/Perl/whatever in Resources. From there it's just a matter of setting up an `NSTask` to launch and pipe the aux program's output back into your main executable. More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208696/nstask-and-nspipe-example-to-comunicate-with-the-command-line-objective-c).